# As part of our project we want to capture the information available in JIRA for our sprint into a databse"

Tags: jira, jira-agile

As part of our new project we are trying to build a report using tableau.The report presents the information for a sprint as per the requirement.Currently we are manually updating the data source for the report.
"Is there a way through which i can access the JIRA information for a sprint and store it in a database so that i can abolish the manual updates".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, due to Jira's popularity there is a Jira API for the vast majority of programming languages with which you could accomplish this.

I personally would suggest the jira-python api due to it's vast documentation that can be found here: https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#jira.

Then you would simply call `sprints(...)` or `sprints_by_name(...)`, and iterate through the results printing relevant information into your database.

Comment: Thanks @Philip DiSarro